# csrf token mismatch during curl form submission in laravel5

Tags: curl, laravel-5, csrf-protection

I am trying to submit a form using curl post method.I have set csrf token properly to the form.But it shows TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:.I am stuck on it and searched on the web.But didn't get any solution.

Comment: You need to include your csrf token in the curl form submission - or you need to disable csrf protection on that route...

Answer (score 0):

Your form should look like this

```
@extends('layout.main')
@section('content')
<form  action="{{URL::route('give-the-route')}}"   method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder=" Title">
<textarea name="description" cols="45" rows="5"placeholder="Brief Description "></textarea>
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
<input type="submit" value="Publish"><br>

</form>

@stop
```

i mean donot forget to write following line

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@extends('layout.main')
@section('content')
<form  action="{{URL::route('give-the-route')}}"   method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder=" Title">
    <textarea name="description" cols="45" rows="5"placeholder="Brief Description "></textarea>

    <!-- dont forgot to use this -->
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

    <input type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
@stop
```

Answer (score -1):

CSRF is now a "middleware" registered globally in App\Http\Kernel.php in Laravel 5. Removing it will default to no CSRF protection (Laravel4 behavior).
Comment out or remove this line in Kernel.php

before:

```
protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
];
```

after:

```
protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    // 'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
];
```

Comment: It's dangerous to recommend this without also mentioning the security risks inherent in taking this approach. CSRF protection is there for a reason, and people who disable it should understand the danger of doing so, or at the very least, be told there is some danger in doing so.